# child div dont show up- background color dont change

Tags: html, css

Please tell whats wrong with my code ? why no background color gets applied to child divs

```
<div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="position:
 relative; width: 3%; height: 636px; float: left; top: -80px;">
<div style="width:50%;background:black;"></div>
<div style="width:50%;background:white;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add height in px to your child elements

Comment: and remove top :- 80 px into add margin-top:-80px;

Comment: i did both ..no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define dimensions to the inner div tags and increase the width of outer div to see your output.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="position: relative; width: 3%; height: 636px; float: left; top: -80px; ">
<div style="width:50%;background:black; height:100%"></div>
<div style="width:50%;background:white; height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the div position based on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="position:
 relative; width: 367%; ; float: left; top: 80px;">
<div style="width:50%;background:black;">sdfgsdfgsdfg</div>
<div style="width:50%;background:gray;">dsfgsdfgsdfg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

# Please add height in px. Like This and remove position:relative #

```
<div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="width: 3%; height: 636px; float: left; top: -80px;">
<div style="width:50%;background:black;height:50px;"></div>
<div style="width:50%;background:white;height:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add height.

```
 <div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="position:
 relative; width: 200px; height: 636px; float: left; top: 0px;">
   <div style="width:100px; height:50px; background:red; float:left;">Test</div>
   <div style="width:100px; height:50px; background:yellow; float:right;">Demo</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-2 line wall-left" style="position: relative; width: 100%; ; float: left; top: 80px;">
 <div style="width:50%;background:black;height:20em"></div>
 <div style="width:50%;background:gray;height:20em"></div>
</div>
```